# Are there official canon rules for DC comics superheroes, especially Superman?

Tags: dc, canon, superman

Superman franchise includes DC comics, as well as movies, TV cartoons and TV series.

Are they all owned by DC?

Are there specific rules as to keeping to/preserving canon on assorted properties involving Superman?

(e.g. similar to Lucas canon levels)?

<sub>I'm referring to rules established by IP holders, not some collective opinion of fans</sub>

Comment: I've edited the wording, feel free to roll back.

Comment: @Pureferret - I like the edit, thanks. I added a clarification to prevent "well I think only original Action Comics *shoud* be canon" responses

Comment: ["Spider-Man must be white and straight, say Sony"](http://variety.com/2015/film/news/sony-hack-peter-parker-spider-man-white-straight-1201524150/)

Answer (score 2):

Superman is a franchise of DC Comics which is in turn owned by Time Warner.  They license his image and story for movies, TV, books, radio, etc. etc.

As for canon rules I would expect that like all other licensed properties there are rules that must be followed and things you cannot do to the character.

However, ownership of Superman may change in 2013 due to recent court rulings about who owns what.  This also explains some of the recent changes to Superman's costume.

From Variety: [Can Superman be split in two?](http://www.variety.com/article/VR1118037679)

Edited to add this link to the [DC Rights and Permission Submission Guidelines](http://www.dccomics.com/about/dcc_randp.pdf)

Comment: While there may be rules to be followed, there have been several *very different* portrayals of Superman, Metropolis, and associated characters throughout the years and different media.  I'd expect it would be *very* difficult, probably nigh-impossible, to reconcile *all* the versions of Superman into one canon.