# Is the Aquaman symbol an 'A'?

Tags: dc, symbols, aquaman

Most people know that the Superman symbol  is not an **S**, it just happens to looks like one.
[image]

(Related: [Why was the Superman's symbol an *English* letter "S"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11079/why-was-the-supermans-symbol-an-english-letter-s))

## Is the same true of the Aquaman symbols,

## [image]  or[image] ?

Or does it legitimately stand for either *Aquaman* or *Atlantis* ?

Answer (score 9):

**The A on Aquaman's belt is a glyph which stands for Atlantis.**

As shown here from *Aquaman (New 52)* #4:

[image]

It's explicitly mentioned in *Aquaman (New 52)* #5:

[image]

The only piece of actual Atlantean writing I've been able to find is by Atlanna (Aquaman's mother), taken from *Aquaman: Time and Tide* #1 (from 1993):
[image]

This appears to be using an English alphabet, suggesting that it is both the symbol for Atlantis, and an A.

This text came from the closing narrative of *The Atlantis Chronicles* #7 (from 1990). Here she is talking about the journal:

[image]

And writing in it:

[image]

I've not been able to see anything to suggest a distinctive Atlantean alphabet within DC Comics lore, such as there is for Kryptonian and Superman's "S".

---

[IGN](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2015/02/21/aquaman-costume-breakdown) mentions this when discussing the film costume:

> The "A" on his belt is of course the "A" for Aquaman. However, just as
>   Superman's "S" shield has gone on to become a family crest and a
>   symbol for hope, so has Aquaman's "A" in the comics. Firstly, the
>   symbol represents Atlantis in the Atlantean alphabet.

Comment: Of course, it’s not *actually* an “A”. It’s missing the cross-bar.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite or it needs a hole drilling in it...

Comment: @NikolaiDante:   Well, we know it's not an A.   But you're right that 'it's a glyph' doesn't tell us if it's an Atlantean letter.   In fact using the word *glyph* rather than *letter* possibly suggests it's not.   We'd need evidence that either it's a special glyph outside their writing system, or that their writing system is not alphabetic.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Maybe it's a lambda, for 'lantis.